# different CSS behavior in Firefox vs Chrome - slider example

Tags: javascript, html, css

My first question on Stackoverflow :) I have this situation. I build a slider trying to get with js the value and displaying in a box. Additionally I want to hide the slider thumb and replace it with my icon.. in Chrome is all nice and good but the in Firefox the original thumb of the slider is still rendered and displayed.

Any I dean what I'm doing wrong in CSS? Thanks in advance!

```js
let slider = document.getElementById("slider_qt");
let selector = document.getElementById("selector");
let SelectValue = document.getElementById("SelectValue");

SelectValue.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider_qt.oninput = function () {
  SelectValue.innerHTML = this.value;
  selector.style.left = this.value + "%";
};
```

```css
.container_quality_tools {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.slider_text {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#slider_qt {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  height: 7px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#slider_qt::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

#selector {
  position: absolute;
  left: 85%;
  margin-top: -10%;
}

.SelectorBtn {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-image: url("../media/slider-icon-14.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}

#SelectValue {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: -2px;
  background: #feb360;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#SelectValue::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 12px solid #feb360;
  border-left: 10px solid #f1f0f0;
  border-right: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="container_quality_tools">
              <p class="slider_text">Quality Tools</p>
              <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="90" id="slider_qt">
              <div id="selector">
                <div class="SelectorBtn"></div>
                <div id="SelectValue"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

Make background and border disappear with `-moz-range-thumb` pseudo selector.

```css
#slider_qt::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
```

It looks broken in the snippet, but I think it would work in your code.

```js
let slider = document.getElementById("slider_qt");
let selector = document.getElementById("selector");
let SelectValue = document.getElementById("SelectValue");

SelectValue.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider_qt.oninput = function() {
  SelectValue.innerHTML = this.value;
  selector.style.left = this.value + "%";
};
```

```css
.container_quality_tools {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

.slider_text {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#slider_qt {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  height: 7px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#slider_qt::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

#slider_qt::-moz-range-thumb {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

#selector {
  position: absolute;
  left: 85%;
  margin-top: -10%;
}

.SelectorBtn {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-image: url("../media/slider-icon-14.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}

#SelectValue {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: -2px;
  background: #feb360;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#SelectValue::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 12px solid #feb360;
  border-left: 10px solid #f1f0f0;
  border-right: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="container_quality_tools">
      <p class="slider_text">Quality Tools</p>
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="90" id="slider_qt">
      <div id="selector">
        <div class="SelectorBtn"></div>
        <div id="SelectValue"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, that does not fix it. I cannot add photos to your answer but now the thumb is white, center aligned on the slider and  visible

Answer (score 0):

``` in the end I was able to solve it like this! Thx all for support! ``

```
#slider_qt::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```